# mmap returning 'No such file or directory'

Tags: c, mmap

I'm trying to `mmap()` a file descriptor to memory but I'm getting errors.

LOG_BUFFER_SIZE is defined as 500.

```
printf("fcntl fd check: %d\n", fcntl(ss->fd_log, F_GETFD));
ss->log_mmap = mmap(NULL, LOG_BUFFER_SIZE, PROT_WRITE | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, ss->fd_log, 0);

if (ss->data_mmap == NULL){
    printf("mmap() error: %s (errno=%d)\n", strerror(errno), errno);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

The file descriptor is valid, as I've checked:

```
fcntl fd check: 1
mmap() error for fd #6: No such file or directory (errno=2)
```

This is the strace:

```
access("../ss_data/SunLoadRight", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("../ss_data/log/SunLoadRight.log", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_APPEND|O_CLOEXEC, 0662) = 6
fcntl(6, F_GETFD)                       = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC)
write(1, "fcntl fd check: 1\n", 18fcntl fd check: 1
)     = 18
mmap(NULL, 500, PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, 6, 0) = 0x7f624c426000
write(1, "mmap() error for fd #6: No such "..., 60mmap() error for fd #6: No such file or directory (errno=2)
) = 60
setitimer(ITIMER_PROF, {it_interval={0, 0}, it_value={0, 0}}, NULL) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPROF, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f624be704b0}, NULL, 8) = 0
open("gmon.out", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_NOFOLLOW, 0666) = 7
write(7, "gmon\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 20) = 20
writev(7, [{"\0", 1}, {"\320\33@\0\0\0\0\0\354\370@\0\0\0\0\0H7\0\0d\0\0\0seconds\0"..., 40}, {"\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 28304}], 3) = 28345
writev(7, [{"\1", 1}, {"\320*@\0\0\0\0\0$\35@\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0", 20}, {"\1", 1}, {"\300,@\0\0\0\0\0A\255@\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0", 20}, {"\1", 1}, {"\320,@\0\0\0\0\0\222\265@\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0", 20}, {"\1", 1}, {"\340,@\0\0\0\0\0n\265@\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0", 20}, {"\1", 1}, {"\360,@\0\0\0\0\0\341\316@\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0", 20}, {"\1", 1}, {"0-@\0\0\0\0\0\367\342@\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0", 20}, {"\1", 1}, {"\240-@\0\0\0\0\0>\321@\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0", 20}, {"\1", 1}, {"0/@\0\0\0\0\0\22\300@\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0", 20}, {"\1", 1}, {"01@\0\0\0\0\0\37\275@\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0", 20}, {"\1", 1}, {"\2601@\0\0\0\0\0\232\310@\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0", 20}, {"\1", 1}, {"\320\257@\0\0\0\0\0\246\262@\0\0\0\0\0P\0\0\0", 20}, {"\1", 1}, {"0\260@\0\0\0\0\0-\256@\0\0\0\0\0P\0\0\0", 20}, {"\1", 1}, {"\220\261@\0\0\0\0\0\22\300@\0\0\0\0\0P\0\0\0", 20}, {"\1", 1}, {"\300\262@\0\0\0\0\0-\256@\0\0\0\0\0P\0\0\0", 20}, {"\1", 1}, {"\200\265@\0\0\0\0\0\"\264@\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0", 20}, {"\1", 1}, {"\240\265@\0\0\0\0\0\"\264@\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0", 20}, ...], 62) = 651
close(7)                                = 0
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

This is all pretty new stuff to me, so I'm probably making some basic mistake somewhere. Something with the flags I guess?

Comment: Assigning to `ss->log_mmap` then checking `ss->data_mmap` is suspicious. Also `PROT_WRITE | PROT_WRITE`? Also look at what the man page says for the return value of mmap in case of failure.

Comment: The second output line does not match the second `printf`. Where does the `" for fd #6"` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `ss->log_mmap` but checking `ss->data_mmap`.

From your strace, `mmap()` has returned a valid pointer.  It does not look like anything incorrect has happened or that there has been any failure.  I suspect your `mmap()` has worked fine.  Also, `ENOENT` is not a valid error code for `mmap()` to return, so it's likely you are checking `errno` when there is no error from the `mmap()`.

On failure, `mmap()` returns `MAP_FAILED`, not `NULL`.  They do not have the same value.

A *private* write only mapping of a file does not seem very useful.  You will not write to the file, just to a private memory region you cannot read and no other process can see.  You probably want `MAP_SHARED` so that writes can go to the file.